# Set chart.js Y axis max and step size values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I wrote a simple line chart using charts.js which updates the data with ajax calls. And I have set the y-axis max and step size values according to the data by updating the chart options. Now I need to update those values when I disable a dataset by clicking it on the legends. how do I do call a function to set those values whenever a dataset is disabled?

The chart:

```js
var mainChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: function(v) {
            // fornating tick labels
          },
        },
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          // formatting tooltip labels
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
```

A function called after getting datasets from ajax:

```
function setAxisScales(chart, data){
    // doing calculations on the data
    chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = max;
    chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.stepSize = step_size;
}
```